# Link STL library with Gradle CMake project

Tags: android, stl, cmake, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I have simple Gradle project and trying to add native library building it using CMake

**Root CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(mine_lib)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

configure_file("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/buildinfo/buildinfo.hpp.in" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/buildinfo.hpp")

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${warnings}")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS   "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${warnings}")

add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/data)
include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

add_library(mine_lib SHARED "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/jni/jniwrapper.c")
```

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        defaultConfig {
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    arguments "-DANDROID_STL=system"
                    cppFlags "-fexceptions"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/mine_lib/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs 'src/main/mine_lib/src/'
        }
    }
}
```

In my native library I use part of STL library, for example `cstdint`. And for now I'm getting compilation error which looks like that:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /AndroidSDK/android-sdk-macosx/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /Users/user/IdeaProjects/Sandbox/MyApp/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/mips64 --target mine_lib}
  [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/mine_lib.dir/src/jni/jniwrapper.c.o
  FAILED: /AndroidSDK/android-sdk-macosx/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang  --target=mips64el-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=/AndroidSDK/android-sdk-macosx/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/AndroidSDK/android-sdk-macosx/ndk-bundle/sysroot -Dheif_EXPORTS -I/Users/user/IdeaProjects/Sandbox/HEIFGallery/app/src/main/mine_lib/src/reader -I. -isystem /AndroidSDK/android-sdk-macosx/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/mips64el-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -fintegrated-as -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -fPIC -MD -MT CMakeFiles/mine_lib.dir/src/jni/jniwrapper.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/mine_lib.dir/src/jni/jniwrapper.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/mine_lib.dir/src/jni/jniwrapper.c.o   -c /Users/user/IdeaProjects/Sandbox/MyApp/app/src/main/mine_lib/src/jni/jniwrapper.c
  In file included from /Users/user/IdeaProjects/Sandbox/MyApp/app/src/main/mine_lib/src/jni/jniwrapper.c:2:
  /Users/user/IdeaProjects/Sandbox/MyApp/app/src/main/mine_lib/src/data/dataparser.hpp:16:10: fatal error: 'cstdint' file not found
  #include <cstdint>
           ^~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

What is the problem really is and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding the problem could be solved by using a different C++ Library.

Currently you are specifying the following within the `build.gradle` file:

```
arguments "-DANDROID_STL=system"
```

Which, as stated within the following [documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html), is:

> system: The minimal system C++ runtime library and the default runtime

You'll probably need to change that to another C++ Library but I am not sure which one it would be, could be one of the gnu options. Better yet, it could be solved by removing the statement entirely.

Comment: @rawnald-gregory-erickson were you able to solve the problem?